# NSClient++ rejects connection or fails to send info

Tags: nagios, nrpe, nsclient++

I'm trying to get to work some active checks on Windows endpoint machines, NSClient++ works just fine with my Windows servers but when it comes to checking any endpoint the only response I get is either `could not fetch information from server` or `CRITICAL - Socket timeout`. I've checked my firewall, the endpoints' firewall and AV protection, the config files on the Nagios server and the `nsclient.ini` file, this is the content of my `ini` file:

```
; Undocumented section
[/modules]

; NRPE server - A simple server that listens for incoming NRPE connection and handles them.
NRPEServer = enabled

; NSClient server - A simple server that listens for incoming NSClient (check_nt) connection and handles them. Although NRPE is the preferred method NSClient is fully supported and can be used for simplicity or for compatibility.
NSClientServer = enabled


; Undocumented section
[/settings/default]

; ALLOWED HOSTS - A comaseparated list of allowed hosts. You can use netmasks (/ syntax) or * to create ranges.
allowed hosts = 192.168.x.x

[/settings/NRPE/server]

; Undocumented key
verify mode = none

; Undocumented key
insecure = true
```

The full file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/XTNT8WKh).

Any guidance would be very helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `allowed hosts` value correct for the NSClient listener? This is a common mistake as you need to "whitelist" who is allowed to call it up and run commands.